# How to unbind 'singleclick' event in Openlayers 6 (React)

Tags: javascript, events, openlayers

I want to add a marker on the OpenLayers map with a single-click event. and after adding a marker-> I want to remove this single-click event from the map.

Here is my on-add marker function :

```
    let iconFeature = new OlFeature({
       geometry: new OlPoint(event.coordinate),
       name: 'Somewhere near Nottingham',
       });
       editLayer.getSource().addFeature(iconFeature);
  };
```

This is single-click event:
 `map.on('singleclick', onAddMarker);`

I tried this way, but not working
`map.un('singleclick', onAddMarker);`

Comment: You have to make sure it is the same function object for both calls. In this case you may olso use `map.once('singleclick', onAddMarker)`  to get that functionality.

Comment: yes. I used the same function in both calls. didn't work.

Comment: ```map.once('singleclick', onAddMarker)``` works. Thanks.